# What is the point of travelling?

Tags: online-resources, history

I **believe** that travel enriches one's life in very real ways.  Some ways in  which I **feel** that it improves a person's life are:

- Deeper understanding of other cultures facilitates creative thinking.
- Stepping outside of your comfort zone gives an increased propensity for productive risk-taking.
- First-hand experience with historical sites gives one a better understanding of our common history.

My question is: are there any objective scientific studies which show that travel improves people's lives in measurable ways?

Comment: There may well be, but this doesn't appear to be [in scope](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Migrate to Skeptics.se?

Comment: I've edited your title, as it was sounding very subjective and fluffy. I believe I"ve maintained the question as you intended, and provided an answer.

Comment: @MarkMayo I've rolled back your edit.  I like eye-catching teaser titles.  Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @ChrisMueller Sure, but now it's a different question to your content.  One is what's the point (and answers might be - to explore, or for work, or for photography, or for food), while your other is - is there science.  I suspect you're going to open yourself to close votes this way :(

Comment: The current "click bait" title, makes me come here intending to thump the "close" button. Is that what you want?

Comment: @CMaster I just want you to come and read the rest of the question ;)

Answer (score 5):

Arguably, yes -  [Science proves that travel is the secret to happiness](http://www.traveller.com.au/science-proves-that-travel-is-the-secret-to-happiness-gix3mw).

> A recent study at Cornell University found that spending money on
>   experiences is more likely to bring you lasting happiness than
>   spending money on material objects.

Therefore, instead of spending money on assets to make you happier (tv, clothes, fancy car), you can spend it on experiences such as travel to enrich your live and make you happier.

Secondly, [Planning A Holiday Will Make You Happier According To Science](http://www.2dayfm.com.au/scoopla/travel/blog/planning-a-holiday-will-make-you-happier-according-to-science/).

> A Dutch study from Breda University of Applied Sciences in the
>   Netherlands looked at the link between holidays and happiness by
>   surveying 1530 adults, 974 of whom had been on a trip during the
>   research period.
>
> And they found that people were happiest while anticipating the
>   holiday, not during it!
>
> They suggested that instead of going on one big trip a year, you might
>   be able to boost your happiness levels with a series of short trips
>   spaced a few months apart.

Basically, this gives you reason to dream about and plan travel all day long. It’s good for you. :D